# SQL server connection in Visual Studio stop working

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I was writing a programm, and I used SQL, and it was working just fine, but suddenly it can't connect to the server.
This is the error I got:
"A network-related or instance-specific error occured while
establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found
or was not accessible. Verify that the instace name is correct and
that SQL is configured to allow remote connections.
(provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating
Server/Instance Specified)"
I am using Visual Studio 2010, and SQL server 2008.
I can't figure out what the problem is and I'd appreciate anyone who helps.

Comment: You want to access remote sql or local sql..

Comment: I want to connect to local sql

Comment: Apply general error searching principles: What has changed? Can others reach the SQL server? Is the network connection to the server ok? Is the SQL Server Service running? If it is a nemaed instance, is the SQL Server Browser Service running? Are there error entries in the eventlog of your and/or the server machine? Can you connect to other servers? Each of the answers should help you to narrow and find the issue.

Comment: if you have sql server installed in you PC and ur application is running against it , first check whether u can login to SQL server using windows authentication / SQL authentication if you have created username and password for a login

Comment: how do I check the answers for those questions?

Comment: I can't connect to SQL server using windows authentication nor SQL authentication

Comment: I found the problem, turns out that for some reason my SQL server has stopped, anyway thanks for all of the help.

Answer (score 0):

open the dbms and try to make an instance of the server, input the IP of the database used in your application and try to ping it, most likely from there on you'll figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `SQL server service` is running or no.

Open **run**. Write in text box i.e.  `services.msc`. Find `SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)` right click on it and select start.